# sitemap.xml empty for static urls in Django

Tags: django, sitemap

I have a Django project and I am trying to create a sitemap for my static urls (no Models). However, when running `python manage.py runserver` and going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml`, I get it empty:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></urlset>
```

My code looks like this:

```
#urls.py
from main_app.sitemaps import StaticSitemap

sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticSitemap(),
}

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    ...
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
...
)
```

and

```
#sitemaps.py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.urls import reverse

class StaticSitemap(Sitemap):
     priority = 0.5
     changefreq = 'weekly'
     i18n = True

     def location(self, item):
         return reverse(item)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) shows an example with `Models` and it modifies the function `items`; but since I do not have, I am not sure if I am missing something there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what the problem was.

It seems that you need to define the function `items` anyway.

```
def items(self):
    list_of_url_names = ['home', 'about', ..., 'contact']
    return list_of_url_names
```

and then `sitemap.xml` is not empty anymore.